# Equivalent of Matlab's 'fit' for Gaussian mixture models in R?

Tags: r, matlab, curve-fitting, gaussian, mixture-model

I have some time series data that looks like this:

```
x <- c(0.5833, 0.95041, 1.722, 3.1928, 3.941, 5.1202, 6.2125, 5.8828, 
4.3406, 5.1353, 3.8468, 4.233, 5.8468, 6.1872, 6.1245, 7.6262, 
8.6887, 7.7549, 6.9805, 4.3217, 3.0347, 2.4026, 1.9317, 1.7305, 
1.665, 1.5655, 1.3758, 1.5472, 1.7839, 1.951, 1.864, 1.6638, 
1.5624, 1.4922, 0.9406, 0.84512, 0.48423, 0.3919, 0.30773, 0.29264, 
0.19015, 0.13312, 0.25226, 0.29403, 0.23901, 0.000213074755156413, 
5.96565965097398e-05, 0.086874, 0.000926808687858284, 0.000904641782399267, 
0.000513042259030044, 0.40736, 4.53928073402494e-05, 0.000765719624469057, 
0.000717419263673946)
```

I would like to fit a curve to this data, using mixtures of one to five Gaussians. In Matlab, I could do the following:

```
fits{1} = fit(1:length(x),x,fittype('gauss1'));
fits{2} = fit(1:length(x),x,fittype('gauss2'));
fits{3} = fit(1:length(x),x,fittype('gauss3'));
```

... and so on.

In R, I am having difficulty identifying a similar method.

```
dat <- data.frame(time = 1:length(x), x = x)
fits[[1]] <- Mclust(dat, G = 1)
fits[[2]] <- Mclust(dat, G = 2)
fits[[3]] <- Mclust(dat, G = 3)
```

... but this does not really seem to be doing quite the same thing. For example, I am not sure how to calculate the R^2 between the fit curve and the original data using the `Mclust` solution.

Is there a simpler alternative in base R to fitting a curve using a mixture of Gaussians?

Comment: What's the formula you are using to calculate r^2 under such a scenario?

Comment: @MrFlick In Matlab it would be: 
`yhat = feval(fits{ii},1:length(x));
tmp = corrcoef(yhat,x);
R2(ii) = tmp(1,2).^2;`

Comment: What does that translate to mathematically? I don't speak matlab.

Comment: The code evaluates the estimated function at the original data points by summing the Gaussians, then calculates the Pearson correlation between the interpolated and original data, and squares it. I think the reason that I cannot calculate the R^2 using `Mclust` is because this method does not involve fitting a height for each Gaussian.

Comment: @MrFlick and @dentist_indeible - what do you think about my answer. I noticed using `nls2` package is better for this, except it is difficult to get it in a functional from. Hence this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46986535/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Function

With the code given below, and with a bit of luck in finding good initial parameters, you should be able to curve-fit Gaussian's to your data.

In the function `fit_gauss`,  aim is to `y ~ fit_gauss(x)` and the number of Gaussians to use is determined by the **length of the initial values** for parameters: `a`, `b`, `d` all of which should be equal length

I have demonstrated curve-fitting of OP's data up to three Gaussian's.

## Specifying Initial Values

This it pretty much most work I have done with `nls` (thanks to OP for that). So, I am not quite sure what is the best method select the initial values. Naturally, they depend on height's of peaks (`a`), mean and standard deviation of `x` around them (`b` and `d`).

One option would be for given number of Gaussian's, try with a number of starting values, and find the one that has best fit based on  residual standard error `fit$sigma`.

I fiddled a bit to find initial parameters, but I dare say the parameters and
the plot with three Gaussian model looks solid.

## Fitting one, two and thee Gaussian's to  Example data

```
ind <- 1 : length(x)

# plot original data
plot(ind, x, pch = 21, bg = "blue")

# Gaussian fit 
fit_gauss <- function(y, x, a, b, d) {

  p_model <- function(x, a, b, d) {
      rowSums(sapply(1:length(a), 
                 function(i) a[i] * exp(-((x - b[i])/d[i])^2)))
  }

  fit <- nls(y ~ p_model(x, a, b, d), 
             start = list(a=a, b = b, d = d), 
             trace = FALSE,  
             control = list(warnOnly = TRUE, minFactor = 1/2048))
  fit
}
```

### Single Gaussian

```
g1 <- fit_gauss(y = x, x = ind, a=1, b = mean(ind), d = sd(ind))
lines(ind, predict(g1), lwd = 2, col = "green")
```

### Two Gaussian's

```
g2 <- fit_gauss(y = x, x = ind, a = c(coef(g1)[1], 1), 
                                b = c(coef(g1)[2], 30), 
                                d = c(coef(g1)[1], 2))
lines(ind, predict(g2), lwd = 2, col = "red")
```

### Three Gaussian's

```
g3 <- fit_gauss(y = x, x = ind, a=c(5, 4, 4), 
                b = c(12, 17, 11), d = c(13, 2, 2))

lines(ind, predict(g3), lwd = 2, col = "black")
```

## Summery of fit with three Gaussian

```
summary(g3)

# Formula: x ~ p_model(ind, a, b, d)
# 
# Parameters:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
#   a1   5.9307     0.5588  10.613 5.93e-14 ***
#   a2   3.5689     0.7098   5.028 8.00e-06 ***
#   a3  -2.2066     0.8901  -2.479 0.016894 *  
#   b1  12.9545     0.5289  24.495  < 2e-16 ***
#   b2  17.4709     0.2708  64.516  < 2e-16 ***
#   b3  11.3839     0.3116  36.538  < 2e-16 ***
#   d1  11.4351     0.8568  13.347  < 2e-16 ***
#   d2   1.8893     0.4897   3.858 0.000355 ***
#   d3   1.0848     0.6309   1.719 0.092285 .  
# ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 0.7476 on 46 degrees of freedom
# 
# Number of iterations to convergence: 34 
# Achieved convergence tolerance: 8.116e-06
```

[image]

Comment: I've been testing this extensively and it seems to work pretty well. The one thing that is bothering me is it will often fit Gaussians with a negative height or variance. Is there any way to force this to not happen or is this just a function of the initial conditions?

Comment: I didn't realize you, or anyone, was interested in it, so I left it in the back-burner to have look more closely later on. Yeah, they can make non-negative. In the case of variance it must, although what matters is variance^2. I'll have a look soon and get a better version.