# nls2 treats vectored initial values as single elements, unlike nls

Tags: r, curve-fitting, nls

I noticed that I can fit parameter vector, as below, using `nls`. This let's me decide the number of parameters I want to fit.  As in the example below; where I am fitting `y = k + a_1 x^2 + a_2 x^3 + a_3 x^3`. I can simply change the number of initial values, which change the number of co-efficients to estimate.

But, this approach doesn't work with `nls2`. It just treats fits the `y = k + a_1 * x`, three times!

My questions is how to get `nls2` to determine the number of parameters to fit based on the initial values - or something similar - as in the case with `nls`.

I don't have a lot of experience with `nls` or similar packages. So, I am trying to mend that. I am guessing `nls2` has more capabilities than `nls`...

## Data and model to fit

```
x <- c(32,64,96,118,126,144,152.5,158)  
y <- c(99.5,104.8,108.5,100,86,64,35.3,15)


model_fun <- function(x, int_sep, para) {
  int_sep +  rowSums(sapply(1:length(para), function(i) para[i] * x^i))
}
```

## With `nls` package

```
mod_nls <- nls(y ~ model_fun(x, int_sep, para), 
             start = list(int_sep = 0, para=c(1, 1, 1)))

mod_nls
# Nonlinear regression model
# model: y ~ model_fun(x, int_sep, para)
# data: parent.frame()
# int_sep      para1      para2      para3 
# 1.269e+02 -1.626e+00  2.910e-02 -1.468e-04 
# residual sum-of-squares: 65.87
# 
# Number of iterations to convergence: 1 
# Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.732e-07
```

## With `nls2` package

```
 mod_nls2 <- nls2(y ~ model_fun(x, int_sep, para), 
                start = list(int_sep = 0, para=c(1, 1, 1)))

mod_nls2
# Nonlinear regression model
# model: y ~ model_fun(x, int_sep, para)
# data: parent.frame()
# int_sep     para 
# 143.0438  -0.5966 
# residual sum-of-squares: 3661
# 
# Number of iterations to convergence: 1 
# Achieved convergence tolerance: 7.602e-09
```

(**edit: I am not interested in this particular model - it seems like an easy example**)

Comment: Your model is linear in its parameters and can (should) thus be fit with lm.

Comment: @Roland, I am not after this particular model at all... just want to know how to do this nls2. thanks.

Comment: @Roland here's another instance where this could be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46986009/3651529

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nls2` converts the `start=` argument to a data frame internally so if you provide it in a form such that `as.data.frame(as.list(start))` works (where in the example "works" means it creates a data frame with 1 row and 2 columns, one column for each of the two parameters -- note that data frame columns can hold complex objects) then you should be OK:

```
nls2(y ~ model_fun(x, int_sep, para), 
  start = list(int_sep = 0, para = I(t(c(1, 1, 1)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to guess regarding the capabilities of `nls2`. Read the documentation. You could report this issue on the package bug tracker, but I suspect @G.Grothendieck won't fix it unless you provide the fix.

Anyway, I would change your function.

```
model_fun <- function(x, int_sep, ...) {
  para <- c(...)
  #I prefer matrix algebra over a loop:
  int_sep +  c(tcrossprod(para, outer(x, seq_along(para), "^")))
}

library(nls2)
mod_nls2 <- nls2(y ~ model_fun(x, int_sep, alpha1, alpha2, alpha3), 
                 start = list(int_sep = 0, alpha1 = 1, alpha2 = 1, alpha3 = 1))

mod_nls2
#Nonlinear regression model
#  model: y ~ model_fun(x, int_sep, alpha1, alpha2, alpha3)
#   data: <environment>
#   int_sep     alpha1     alpha2     alpha3 
# 1.269e+02 -1.626e+00  2.910e-02 -1.468e-04 
# residual sum-of-squares: 65.87
#
#Number of iterations to convergence: 1 
#Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.732e-07
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It is useful, and I was wondering how to get G.Grothendieck's attention.